# ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit Issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am accessing multiple Oracle databases via Linked Server in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  In the last few days I have had stored procedures failing with the referenced error.  I am working to contact the Oracle DBA's but wanted to better understand what causes this error.  Is it that my account has too many queries accessing the servers or that there are too many in general (my and other users).  This is a very large corporate database with 1000's of people accessing it.

My main goal is to be able to speak with the Oracle DBA with some knowledge of what might be going on (i.e., I don't think that I'm in a position to resolve this).  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's profile setting

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE RESOURCE_NAME = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER';
```

You can change it using

```
ALTER PROFILE <profile name> LIMIT SESSIONS_PER_USER <number>;
```

or

```
ALTER PROFILE <profile name> LIMIT SESSIONS_PER_USER UNLIMITED;
```

Comment: That would have to be run on the Oracle instance, correct?  It appeared that way in my research and when I tried in SQL Management Studio it did not work.  Assuming so, I'm guessing that there is a max sessions per user for either individual users (i.e., just me or all individuals) or that there is a setting for groups of users and the group that I belong may need to be increased?

Comment: @chemnteach That is run on the Oracle side.  Profiles can be assigned multiple users, which you can check via: select username from dba_users where profile = 'PROFILENAME';

Answer (score 0):

So, I thought it might be useful to close the loop on this for folks who use MS SQL to talk to Oracle.  What we found was that when my account had a stored procedure hung and I killed it, Oracle did not recognize that I had killed it.  After a few times of this happening, it was possible for it to appear that I had more instances accessing the Oracle database than were visible to me.  Once the Oracle DBA released those jobs all was fine.